# I have created a GStreamer RTSP Server in Python, But I'm having latency issues

Tags: rtsp, python-gstreamer

I have created a GStreamer RTSP Server in Python, and here is a segment of the code:

```
class Factory(GstRtspServer.RTSPMediaFactory):
    def __init__(self, source, path, video_codec, audio_codec, username, password, device_id):
        GstRtspServer.RTSPMediaFactory.__init__(self)
        print("debug:gst_server::Factory::init")
        self.source = source
        self.video_codec = video_codec
        self.audio_codec = audio_codec
        self.path = path
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.device_id = device_id
        self.launch_string ="rtspsrc name=rtspsrc location="****" user-id="****" user-pw="****" latency=0 protocols=4 tcp-timeout=4000000  ! rtph265depay ! h265parse ! vaapih265dec !  queue ! vaapih264enc ! video/x-h264,  profile=constrained-baseline ! h264parse ! rtph264pay  name=pay0  pt=96"
        self.set_eos_shutdown(True)
        self.set_latency(0)
        self.set_shared(True)
        self.set_buffer_size(5242880)
        self.pool_set = GstRtspServer.RTSPAddressPool()
        self.set_address_pool(self.pool_set)
        self.set_launch(self.launch_string)
```

When playing video from the IP camera, there is a 3-second buffer delay in VLC. However, the RTSP server has successfully connected and distributed the IP camera's video stream. Still, I'm experiencing a 3-second buffer delay when playing through the RTSP server. I'd like to know where the issue might be.

Sometimes, when using VLC to play the IPCAM, there is no need for a 3-second buffer. In such cases, the RTSP server does not introduce a 3-second buffer delay. I would appreciate guidance on where the problem may lie.

When playing video from the IP camera, there is a 3-second buffer delay in VLC. However, the RTSP server has successfully connected and distributed the IP camera's video stream. Still, I'm experiencing a 3-second buffer delay when playing through the RTSP server. I'd like to know where the issue might be.

Sometimes, when using VLC to play the IPCAM, there is no need for a 3-second buffer. In such cases, the RTSP server does not introduce a 3-second buffer delay. I would appreciate guidance on where the problem may lie.